# How to integrate an existing API to a new website

Tags: json, api, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

**Hello!** This may be a total rookie question, sorry for that.

I have decent knowledge in HTML/CSS and a little python, and my company that I currently work at has partnered with another business and needs to integrate their existing and pretty complex API into a new-made website that will be for my company, to promote their services and benefit together.

My question is this, the API's url is like this "https://api.website.com/swagger.json", and has an authorization Key. The whole job of integrating it will come to me and I don't know how to proceed because sadly I have minimal knowledge of APIs and how to integrate one into an website for people to get the data from the database.

One thing, the API is getting the data from the database, and for someone to get that data, he must Pay with a Credit Card, so its selling that data basically...

Can someone please guide me a little, how to proceed, what steps are there to take.. I was thinking to build a Django Website with a HTML template, and creating there a button for users to get the data from the database..

I am highly grateful for anyone replying to this, and maybe we partner together!
**Please help me!**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't want to put you down, but you should say you are not the right man for the job and ask to do pair programming with someone more experienced to complete the task and learn how to do it, because there is a LOT of things you need to know...

But, just to give you some clues:

Swagger is API documentation, it shows what entriepoints exists and HTTP methods and urls you have to request to access them.

Entrypoint is a pair of a HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) with a URL pointing to some resource (if this API is REST, could be some other types like graphql, grpc or even SOAP you got to know up front).

There is a thing named CORS that will establish if can consume that API from frontend (fetch function in javascript or some module like axios) or not (must be consumed from server-side like django as you mentioned).

Token could be anything, normally we pass some informations on HTTP request header called Authorization, in all calls, to validate our access to the API.

Been a "real world" API, not does fake things to lear how to program, it could be much more complex than just that... can you see why my advice was to decline the job in favor of someone with more experience and learn from him/her?

Answer (score 0):

What is integration mean? are you trying to consume (get data) if so depending on the language you're using but I would say for language agnostic approach use Javascript/JQuery or other libraries like Angular or Vue or even ReactJS.

Here's an example.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/